# Find child of specific type in render() of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am using Draft.js and need to recurse into `props.children` to find components of type `DraftEditorBlock`.

For some reason, this doesn't really seem to work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DraftEditorBlock } from 'draft-js';
...
export default class MyBlockRenderer extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const firstChild = React.Children.toArray(children)[0];
    if (firstChild instanceof DraftEditorBlock) {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The line where `instanceof` is used causes this error:

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the export called [`EditorBlock` instead of `DraftEditorBlock`](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/d24b80217beb76d4fa37e45835415a5ca7cb5a6f/src/Draft.js#L46)?

Comment: It's possible that DraftEditorBlock is a stateless, functional component, rather than an object.

Comment: @JoelWorsham - Functions are still objects, so that wouldn't lead to the posted error message (it just wouldn't work).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder + @Tholle: first bug is that I should use `EditorBlock` and not `DraftEditorBlock`, but now I just get `false` from all `instanceof` calls. Isn't there any sure fire way to tell if a component is of a certain class, even for functional components?

Answer (score 1):

read the `render()` methods in draftjs source top down. there are still many levels between `DraftEditorBlock` and `DraftEditor`.

I suggest you to cache all created/mounted `DraftEditorBlock`s other than find them in `render()` by:

1. make a component inherit `DraftEditorBlock`, or new component with single `<DraftEditorBlock ... />` child.
2. map the `text` block type to your component with `blockRendererFn`.

should work.